# jQuery onclick event not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery:

```
$("#addfav").click(function(){
    alert('clicked1');
    $("#addfav").attr('id','delfav');
    $("#star").attr('src','<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/star_full.png');
    var data = {
        pet_id: $("#addfav").attr('data-num')
    }
    console.log(data);
})
$("#delfav").click(function(){
    alert('clicked2');
    $("#delfav").attr('id','addfav');
    $("#star").attr('src','<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/star_empty.png');
    var data = {
        pet_id: $("#delfav").attr('data-num')
    }
    console.log(data);
})
```

HTML:

```
<span data-num="42103" id="addfav" style="cursor:pointer"><img id="star" src="http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/assets/images/star_full.png" alt=""></span>
```

It always alerting clicked1 someone can please help me why is it happening?

Comment: use delegation since you are changing always the id  ....you are actually binding the event to the created elements .

Comment: Now what to do?

Comment: Use `.on('click', 'selector' ,function(){})`  check this example with your code https://jsfiddle.net/hf008xyL/